# Yellow fever vaccination for airport transfer?

Tags: health, africa

I'm going on holiday to somewhere where there is a low yellow fever risk, but to get there I have a 4 hour layover in a city with a high yellow fever risk. If I'm not leaving the airport at any time, do I still need to get the yellow fever innoculation?

Comment: You’ll probably get a better answer if you state your transit and final destinations.

Comment: Note that even if it turns out that the vaccination is not mandatory, it might still be advisable to get it. Otherwise, you might get into trouble when your second flight is cancelled, delayed, ... or you have to leave the airport for whatever reason.

Comment: The rules will surely depend on where it is that you're transiting, and possibly where you're travelling to (if they have rules about vaccination for people who've passed through risk areas -- I don't know if that's a thing). It could conceivably be a condition of your travel insurance, too (again, I don't know if that's a thing, but I can imagine them requiring you to take reasonable steps to prevent yourself from getting an expensive-to-treat illness).